# Problem with determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^3$.

Prove that

$det\left(I-\frac{xy^*A}{1+y^*Ax}\right)=\frac{1}{1+y^*Ax}$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Try the [determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma#Statement) with $A:=I$, $u:=-x/(1+y^*Ax)$, and $v:=y^*A$.

Comment: Thanks @AlgebraicPavel , with that the solution is straightforward.